# Cannot load group for JDBC realm user

Tags: security, glassfish, glassfish-3, jdbcrealm

My jdbcRealm has somehow gotten deleted by magic from GlassFish. Now when I try to add it back in, I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: SEC1111: Cannot load group for JDBC realm user [admin].
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
WARNING: Exception
com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException: Login failed: Security Exception
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.LoginContextDriver.doPasswordLogin(LoginContextDriver.java:394)
```

Based on the other answers I've seen on here, the culprit is usually a reserved word being used as a column name but this doesn't seem to be the problem in my case (see screenshot below). We recently had some database model changes so I had to reconfigure the mappings for roles to groups in web.xml and glassfish-web.xml. There are five roles and they are a 1:1 mapping between users.

[image]

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?